# Linq query from multiple sets of nested collections

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm a bit new to Linq. I'm trying to query a collection of items, that are distributed across multiple containing items.
Basically, I'm trying to run a nested query on items in nested collections, that are selected based on some criteria.

Here is an example where I came up with a somewhat ugly method, that achieves the result.

Data item:

```
Class qItem
    Property qName As String
    Property qStrings As List(Of String)
End Class
```

Populated collections:

```
Dim qItems As New List(Of qItem)

qItems.Add(New qItem With {.qName = "Name1", .qStrings = New List(Of String) From {"3243", "324239", "f3f235423"}})
qItems.Add(New qItem With {.qName = "Name2", .qStrings = New List(Of String) From {"3243", "324239", "f3f235423"}})
qItems.Add(New qItem With {.qName = "Name1", .qStrings = New List(Of String) From {"3243r33", "3gfh465239", "r2r23r"}})
qItems.Add(New qItem With {.qName = "Name1", .qStrings = New List(Of String) From {"32f3f3f43", "324239", "f3f235423"}})
```

And the "ugly" query:

```
Dim myQuery = From q In qItems Where q.qName = "Name1"
Dim qResult As New List(Of String)
For Each qlst In myQuery
     qResult.AddRange(qlst.qStrings)
Next
Dim finalQuery = From q In qResult Where q.Contains("f3")
```

Can this be somehow done without running a manual for-each loop to aggregate all the items from different `qStrings`?
To achieve this I would assume, I need to somehow do a `From` for all different items in my collection `qitems`. 

In essence, for the result I need a collection of strings queried from `q.qStrings` from multiple `qItem` obejcts. How would I do this?

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more digging I found the answer I was looking for. 
Turns out you can nest-chain `From` statements. Also I was not familiar with `Select`. 
So, in the end, the working solution for my case is as simple as this.

```
Dim finalQuery = From q In qItems Where q.qName = "Name1"
                 From s In q.qStrings
                 Select s Where s.Contains("f3")
```

And to get a more general collection, a conversion can be added at the end.

```
Dim finalQuery = (From q In qItems Where q.qName = "Name1"
                 From s In q.qStrings
                 Select s Where s.Contains("f3")).ToList
```

Comment: I believe you will still need to iterate finalQuery. `Dim finalQuery = (From q In qItems Where q.qName = "Name1"
                 From s In q.qStrings
                 Select s Where s.Contains("f3")).ToList` will give you a List(Of String) that you can access immediately instead of an IEnumerable.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Edited the answer for more complete information.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend it, basically adding (`And` or `Or`) will continue the `Where` clause.

In your example `qStrings` is a property of `qItem` and you want to query `qStrings` that contains `"f3"`

```
From q In qItems Where q.qName = "Name1" And q.qStrings.Contains("f3")
```

If `qItem` has additional property like `int Id` and want to filter it by 1

```
From q In qItems Where q.qName = "Name1" And q.qStrings.Contains("f3") And q.Id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. That is another and a bit simpler way to do it.
But for the end-result I still need a collection of strings not a collection of objects, that contain collections of strings.
After this query I would still need to run a for-each equivalent in order to build the final collection from each `q.qStrings` of different `qItem`s. I was wondering, maybe there is a more elegant way of doing this at the same time, i.e. something like nested query.

Comment: Besides this wouldn't work as I need it to. The part `q.qStrings.Contains("f3")` checks if the collection contains string item "f3", but I need to check whether the string item contains a substring "f3".